# Method/program for creating a graphical email signature

Tags: graphics-editing

I would like to create a kind of business card for my email signature in Mac OS X, with a nice graphical design. I tried to find software for this but it seems most people use photoshop, etc, which is very complicated. I wonder if you could tell me some other much easier software/method for this, or the approach you follow for my objective.

Comment: Which Operating Ssytem are you using?  Have you checked out [What is a good and free image editor? (Alternative to Photoshop)](http://superuser.com/questions/25451/what-is-a-good-and-free-image-editor-alternative-to-photoshop)?

Comment: To be honest, please don't use images as email signatures. Not only does it waste storage space as well as actual screen space – clients with text-only readers won't even be able to see it.

Comment: Today screen space is the biggest issue - even though I'm fine if my ~/Mail expands to gigabytes, and I can open Thunderbird if needed, there's still only so much the recipient can see and read at once... I personally dislike it when people send a two-line message and append a twenty-line corporate disclaimer. Similarly, a small logo (similar to SuperUser's user boxes) is okay but large images and complicated designs quickly become annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use images. It is very discouraged to use images in mails because that increases mail size unnecessary.

If you really need to use some enhanced design, use html. There is a handy [tutorial](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050706181449478) available on how to inject html signatures to Mail.app. For creating your HTML, you can use a simple text editor or some wysiwyg-software.

It is possible though to create some nice-looking signatures completely without html!

Comment: True, but not an answer.

Comment: You're right, not everything is answering the question - but the core of my message _is_ answering the question. I just added some hints on good mail practise I rate important.